# Arduino DHT11 como adaptar a este código?

Tags: arduino

Como posso usar o sensor dht11 aqui?

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <Ethernet.h>
    #include <SD.h>
    // size of buffer used to capture HTTP requests
    #define REQ_BUF_SZ   60

    // MAC address from Ethernet shield sticker under board
    byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
    IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 120); // IP address, may need to change depending on network
    EthernetServer server(80);  // create a server at port 80
    File webFile;               // the web page file on the SD card
    char HTTP_req[REQ_BUF_SZ] = {0}; // buffered HTTP request stored as null terminated string
    char req_index = 0;              // index into HTTP_req buffer
    boolean LED_state[2] = {0}; // stores the states of the LEDs

    void setup()
    {
    // disable Ethernet chip
    pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
    digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

    Serial.begin(9600);       // for debugging

    // initialize SD card
    Serial.println("Initializing SD card...");
    if (!SD.begin(4)) {
    Serial.println("ERROR - SD card initialization failed!");
    return;    // init failed
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - SD card initialized.");
    // check for index.htm file
    if (!SD.exists("index.htm")) {
    Serial.println("ERROR - Can't find index.htm file!");
    return;  // can't find index file
    }
    Serial.println("SUCCESS - Found index.htm file.");
    // switches
    pinMode(2, INPUT);
    pinMode(3, INPUT);
    // LEDs
    pinMode(6, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(7, OUTPUT);

    Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);  // initialize Ethernet device
    server.begin();           // start to listen for clients
    }

    void loop()
    {
    EthernetClient client = server.available();  // try to get client

    if (client) {  // got client?
    boolean currentLineIsBlank = true;
    while (client.connected()) {
    if (client.available()) {   // client data available to read
    char c = client.read(); // read 1 byte (character) from client
    // limit the size of the stored received HTTP request
    // buffer first part of HTTP request in HTTP_req array (string)
    // leave last element in array as 0 to null terminate string (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)
    if (req_index < (REQ_BUF_SZ - 1)) {
    HTTP_req[req_index] = c;          // save HTTP request character
    req_index++;
    }
    // last line of client request is blank and ends with \n
    // respond to client only after last line received
    if (c == '\n' && currentLineIsBlank) {
    // send a standard http response header
    client.println("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    // remainder of header follows below, depending on if
    // web page or XML page is requested
    // Ajax request - send XML file
    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "ajax_inputs")) {
    // send rest of HTTP header
    client.println("Content-Type: text/xml");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    client.println();
    SetLEDs();
    // send XML file containing input states
    XML_response(client);
    }
    else {  // web page request
    // send rest of HTTP header
    client.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive");
    client.println();
    // send web page
    webFile = SD.open("index.htm");        // open web page file
    if (webFile) {
        while(webFile.available()) {
            client.write(webFile.read()); // send web page to client
        }
        webFile.close();
    }
    }
    // display received HTTP request on serial port
    Serial.print(HTTP_req);
    // reset buffer index and all buffer elements to 0
    req_index = 0;
    StrClear(HTTP_req, REQ_BUF_SZ);
    break;
    }
    // every line of text received from the client ends with \r\n
    if (c == '\n') {
    // last character on line of received text
    // starting new line with next character read
    currentLineIsBlank = true;
    } 
    else if (c != '\r') {
    // a text character was received from client
    currentLineIsBlank = false;
    }
    } // end if (client.available())
    } // end while (client.connected())
    delay(1);      // give the web browser time to receive the data
    client.stop(); // close the connection
    } // end if (client)

    // read buttons and debounce
    ButtonDebounce();
    }

    // function reads the push button switch states, debounces and latches the LED states
    // toggles the LED states on each push - release cycle
    // hard coded to debounce two switches on pins 2 and 3; and two LEDs on pins 6 and 7
    // function adapted from Arduino IDE built-in example:
    // File --> Examples --> 02.Digital --> Debounce
    void ButtonDebounce(void)
    {
    static byte buttonState[2]     = {LOW, LOW};   // the current reading from the input pin
    static byte lastButtonState[2] = {LOW, LOW};   // the previous reading from the input pin

    // the following variables are long's because the time, measured in miliseconds,
    // will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
    static long lastDebounceTime[2] = {0};  // the last time the output pin was toggled
    long debounceDelay = 50;         // the debounce time; increase if the output flickers

    byte reading[2];

    reading[0] = digitalRead(2);
    reading[1] = digitalRead(3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    if (reading[i] != lastButtonState[i]) {
    // reset the debouncing timer
    lastDebounceTime[i] = millis();
    }

    if ((millis() - lastDebounceTime[i]) > debounceDelay) {
    // whatever the reading is at, it's been there for longer
    // than the debounce delay, so take it as the actual current state:

    // if the button state has changed:
    if (reading[i] != buttonState[i]) {
    buttonState[i] = reading[i];

    // only toggle the LED if the new button state is HIGH
    if (buttonState[i] == HIGH) {
    LED_state[i] = !LED_state[i];
    }
    }
    }
    } // end for() loop

    // set the LEDs
    digitalWrite(6, LED_state[0]);
    digitalWrite(7, LED_state[1]);

    // save the reading.  Next time through the loop,
    // it'll be the lastButtonState:
    lastButtonState[0] = reading[0];
    lastButtonState[1] = reading[1];
    }

    // checks if received HTTP request is switching on/off LEDs
    // also saves the state of the LEDs
    void SetLEDs(void)
    {
    // LED 1 (pin 6)
    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED1=1")) {
    LED_state[0] = 1;  // save LED state
    digitalWrite(6, HIGH);
    }
    else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED1=0")) {
    LED_state[0] = 0;  // save LED state
    digitalWrite(6, LOW);
    }
    // LED 2 (pin 7)
    if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED2=1")) {
    LED_state[1] = 1;  // save LED state
    digitalWrite(7, HIGH);
    }
    else if (StrContains(HTTP_req, "LED2=0")) {
    LED_state[1] = 0;  // save LED state
    digitalWrite(7, LOW);
    }
    }

    // send the XML file with analog values, switch status
    //  and LED status
    void XML_response(EthernetClient cl)
    {
    int analog_val;            // stores value read from analog inputs
    int count;                 // used by 'for' loops
    int sw_arr[] = {2, 3};  // pins interfaced to switches

    cl.print("<?xml version = \"1.0\" ?>");
    cl.print("<inputs>");
    // checkbox LED states
    // LED1
    cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[0]) {
    cl.print("checked");
    }
    else {
    cl.print("unchecked");
    }
    cl.println("</LED>");
    // button LED states
    // LED3
    cl.print("<LED>");
    if (LED_state[1]) {
    cl.print("on");
    }
    else {
    cl.print("off");
    }
    cl.println("</LED>");
    cl.print("</inputs>");
    }

    // sets every element of str to 0 (clears array)
    void StrClear(char *str, char length)
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    str[i] = 0;
    }
    }

    // searches for the string sfind in the string str
    // returns 1 if string found
    // returns 0 if string not found
    char StrContains(char *str, char *sfind)
    {
    char found = 0;
    char index = 0;
    char len;

    len = strlen(str);

    if (strlen(sfind) > len) {
    return 0;
    }
    while (index < len) {
    if (str[index] == sfind[found]) {
    found++;
    if (strlen(sfind) == found) {
    return 1;
    }
    }
    else {
    found = 0;
    }
    index++;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso pode ser adequado facilmente com o código abaixo! É só encaixar cada instrução em seu lugar certo e já era! Acredito que existam maneiras mais fáceis de fazer o que você está tentando fazer...

```
#include <DHT.h>

#define DHTPIN A1
#define DHTTYPE DHT11

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   dht.begin();
}

void loop() {
int temp = dht.readTemperature();
char recebido;
recebido = Serial.read();
   if(recebido == 't'){
      Serial.print("Temperatura ");
      Serial.print(temp);
      Serial.println("C°");
      delay(2000);
   }
}
```